# Tub cracked side lip, replace or patch up?

Tags: repair, bathtub, replacement, crack

I have a newly installed tub and unfortunately it has a crack down the outer edge or front lip about 1 to 2 inches and it also goes all the way to the edge.

I am afraid of it running and getting bigger, and I am not sure the material if it is acrylic, polyester or fibreglass if that matters?

I am wondering should I replace entire tub or patch it up? Thanks for any advice or knowledge.

[image]

Comment: I have heard that drilling a hole at the end of a crack stops it. I have no idea if that is true or not. So I am happy if somebody shoots this comment down in flames...

Comment: @Oldfart it’s true - as ling as you go to the **end** of the crack - and that “end” may well be further along than you would think. But it is down to relieving stresses and Von Mises stress theory.

Comment: It is a new construction so even bathroom is new and I initially requested a replacement however sales for contractor wanted me to patch. But now my understanding is that the underlying issue can be if tub isn't properly bedded putting strain/flex forces worsening current situation or creating others especially on new install before any use. I will stay firm with a replacement request. @all here, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to repair that crack then the complete length needs supporting as it is flexing too much.

I had one where we noticed the flex early and I fitted a beam with supports underneath - made access a bit more difficult but still ok.

Seen one where the next crack developed a short distance down from the repair so think carefully about the real cause as well.

Comment: I agree it looks like the tub was not bedded correctly a common diy problem the tub needs to be bedded so it won’t flex then a patch on the outside will probably be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you just had it replaced then that means that your contractor should fix this issue.

Regarding fix vs replace: I suggest trying to work that out with your contractor. If the decision is to attempt a repair I would be sure to get IN WRITING that they are guarantying the repair of the tub. You paid your good money to have your new bathroom and you deserve to have it done correctly. The crack is there because something wasn't done correctly. That's on your contractor.

A fix is cheaper. Your contractor will push HARD for that solution. You are not obligated to accept that solution. A fix can be a solution, assuming it works over time, and looks good (and not cheap). It will only work over time if the source of the crack is addressed.

Comment: for longer term usage would a fix be worth it? Or is this bad enough that I should ask for a replacement?

Comment: It's hard for me to answer without knowing more information that I can get here. I suggest trying to work that out with your contractor. If the decision is to attempt a repair I would be sure to get IN WRITING that they are guarantying the repair of the tub. You paid your good money to have your new bathroom and you desire to have it done correctly. The crack is there because something wasn't done correctly. That's on your contractor.

Comment: I would ask IF the op did the install or it was done by a pro, this is a very common diy mistake. Bedding the tub and patching may work and will be much cheaper than a new tub.

Comment: I hear you but I decided to, as my grandfather used to say, cut out the middle man. There were two options, either the OP was/is dodging/avoiding that or they did hire a contractor. I had to go with the latter as it's pretty hard to help someone that isn't being straight. I would have chosen not to respond at all. And their response 'should I ask for a replacement' seems to clearly imply that they did not install it and so I feel confident that they have a contractor. Or I'm being mislead

And I agree with you, a fix is cheaper. Assuming it works over time, and looks good (and not cheap)

Comment: Hi; would you integrate the info in your comments into your actual answer? Thanks.

Comment: The contractor should replace the tub, properly. I happen to have a very nice tub with a crack I think I can repair - got it for $50 from the contractor who replaced it after a tile subcontractor cracked it.

Comment: Daniel Griscom: comments added, thank you